# How do i enable IPN in Paypal Sandbox?

Tags: paypal-sandbox

I am trying to find the IPN settings for a business paypal sandbox account. I have both a type personal and business. I just see profile >settings and the choices Payment review and Negative testing.

I sign in under the Business account but i can't find the IPN settings?

Comment: what settings you want to make ?

Comment: @TrimantraSoftwareSolution i am trying to enable IPN so my develop Wordpress webshop gets a "payment accepted" notification. But i get a lot of 400 bad request on sandbox.paypal.com like on https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/customerprofile/summary.view?nav=0%2e5